# Hail API AccessToken method

Tags: api, rest

I'm trying to get access token from hail after get an authorization code from url `https://hail.to/oauth/authorise?client_id={$client_id}&redirect_uri={$redirect_url}&response_type=code&scope=user.basic+user.manage+org.basic+content.read+content.read+content.connections`

After getting the code from the above url, the documentation they provide does not state what should be the correct parameter to get an `access_token`. The documentation says it should be a POST method to get access token by using  url `https://hail.to/api/v1/oauth/access_token?client_id={$client_id}&client_secret={$client_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={$client_access_token_code}&redirect_uri={$redirect_url}`.

When I try this, I get the following error response:

```
{
    "error" : {
        "message" : "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"grant_type\" parameter.",
        "error_code" : null
    }
}
```

If anyone has faced this problem, please help me out on this.
I don't know what should be the correct parameter for grant type.